# Access using passthrough query for subform

Tags: ms-access

I have a subform in which I use a passthrough query for the fields. I keep getting an error message that says "You can't use a pass-through query as a recordsource for a subform". I've also tried making a separate regular query of my passthrough query to use for the subform, but I still get the same message.

In searching around the web, the main solutions I have seen is to make a temporary table of the results of the passthrough query then bind the subform to the temp table. I'm not really wild about this idea because it seems to just clutter up the Access database, so I wanted to see if anyone else had any ideas/or suggestions.

Does anyone know of another way (besides creating a temp table) to use a passthrough query for a subform?

FYI, I know passthrough queries are read-only, but so is my subform.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use a query on a linked table instead of a passthrough query?  That worked for me. I have not tried it but maybe a regular query on your pass-through will work

Comment: You can use the actual view or stored procedure that makes up your pass through query and use VBA code in your Form Open event to assign it to the subform's recordset property.

Comment: JShort, I did create a query on the linked table, but there was a real lag with the performance.